# First slide of Beamer to SVG

Tags: svg

I have a Beamer presentation. I've always converted it to PDF with:

`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error slides.tex`

How can I export the *first slide* of a Beamer presentation to SVG?

Comment: You could use inkscape to convert the pdf to svg

Comment: Perhaps [pdf2svg](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) could be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

```
latex mydoc.tex
```

then

```
dvisvgm --font-format=woff mydoc.dvi
```

By default, since SVG is a one-page graphics format, `dvisvgm` converts only the first page, as requested by the OP, of the input DVI.

To process all pages of the DVI, which generates one numbered SVG per input page, run

```
dvisvgm -p1,- --font-format=woff mydoc.dvi
```

Usable graphics formats for embedding are EPS, PNG, JPEG, SVG. Only EPS gets emedded as inline SVG thanks to the Ghostscript library used by `dvisvgm`. (Ghostscript must be installed on the system.) Other graphics formats remain external and must be shipped with the main document SVG output.

More info available through `dvisvgm` man page:

```
man dvisvgm
```

with a TeXLive installation on Linux.